# How to sort an array with date and values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array in this format. I need to sort it descending:

```
   [{
      "9-Sep" : 6
    }, {
      "8-Sep" : 11
    }, {
      "7-Sep" : 4
    }, {
      "6-Sep" : 11
    }, {
      "5-Sep" : 16
    }, {
      "4-Sep" : 14
    }, {
      "3-Sep" : 3
    }, {
      "2-Sep" : 11
    }, {
      "15-Sep" : 28
    }, {
      "14-Sep" : 6
    }, {
      "13-Sep" : 8
    }, {
      "12-Sep" : 15
    }, {
      "11-Sep" : 24
    }, {
      "10-Sep" : 19
    }];
```

I am using this function but it is sorting only if values are not there.

```
function myname() {
    var ad = new Date(),
        bd = new Date(),
        months = {
            Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5,
            Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov:10, Dec:12
        };

    json.sort(function (a,b) {
        var as = a.split('-'),
            bs = b.split('-');

        ad.setDate(as[0]);
        ad.setMonth(months[as[1]]);
        bd.setDate(bs[0]);
        bd.setMonth(months[bs[1]]);

        return ad - bd;
    });
};
```

How to sort the above array with values?

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It's rather about how to process arrays/objects in JavaScript. *How* you obtained the data (e.g. via JSON) is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: What does *"It is sorting only if values are not there"* mean? What values are you talking about?

Comment: [ {
      "6-Sep" 
    }, {
      "5-Sep" 
    }, {
      "4-Sep" 
    }, {
      "3-Sep" 
    }
    ]; If it like this above function is sorting. but If come with values like above json ,then am not able to sort..?

Comment: Ah, so it works if you have an array of strings (`["9-Sep", "8-Sep", ...]`) but not an array of objects (`[{"9-Sep" : 6}, {"8-Sep" : 11}, ...]`). If you have an array of objects, then `a` and `b` will be objects and you'd have to extract the property name first. It might be easier to use an array of arrays instead: `[["9-Sep", 6], ["8-Sep", 11], ...]`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah u r right.. My collection structure is restricted to the above format. So i did not think out of box.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you'll probably have to extract your data to a different format to sort it:

```
var newArray = [];

//Extract array of transformed objects
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var element = json[i];
    for(var key in element) {
        if(element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newArray.push({ date: key, val: element[key]})
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Sort transformed array
newArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    var as = a.date.split('-'),
        bs = b.date.split('-');

    ad.setDate(as[0]);
    ad.setMonth(months[as[1]]);
    bd.setDate(bs[0]);
    bd.setMonth(months[bs[1]]);

    return ad - bd;
});

//Transform back to old format
for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    var x = {};
    x[newArray[i].date] = newArray[i].val;
    json[i] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code works fine and does what you actually want.

```
<script>    
     records = [{ "21-Feb": "IndPak" }, { "12-Oct": "AusSA" }, { "9-Sep": "WINZD" }, { "1-Jun": "NZDSL" }];
                    months = {
                        "Jan": 0, "Feb": 1, "Mar": 2, "Apr": 3, "May": 4, "Jun": 5,
                        "Jul": 6, "Aug": 7, "Sep": 8, "Oct": 9, "Nov": 10, "Dec": 12
                    };

                    records = records.sort(function (d1, d2) {

                        var date1 = new Date(), date2 = new Date()
                        for (var prop in d1) {

                            if (d1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                                day = prop.split("-")[0];
                                month = prop.split("-")[1];

                                date1.setDate(parseInt(day));
                                date1.setMonth(parseInt(months[month]));
                            }
                        }
                        for (var prop in d2) {

                            if (d2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                                day = prop.split("-")[0];
                                month = prop.split("-")[1];

                                date2.setDate(parseInt(day));
                                date2.setMonth(parseInt(months[month]));
                            }
                        }

                        return date1 - date2; // Ascending
                        //return date2 - date1; // Descending
                    });

    </script>
```